# Python: trouble editing string in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, rounding

So this is driving me crazy.  I need to take a text file containing (all in one line)

> mmfff m fm fmm FFF mmmmmm mfmfmf  mmmfff MM fmmmf

and manipulate it in a program.  It needs to open and read the file, edit out the spaces, and change all letters to caps.  Then it needs to print the edited file, count the m's and f's and output them as a percent of the whole.

```
# A program to determine male to female ratio

import math

main = raw_input("Enter the name of your file: ")

inputFile = open(main, 'r+')

gender =(inputFile.read().replace(" ", "").replace("f", "F").replace("m", "M"))

inputFile.close()

inputFile= open(main, 'r+')

inputFile.write(gender)

inputFile.close()

print gender

fletter = 0

mletter = 0

mletter = gender.count('M')

fletter = gender.count('F')

mletter =((mletter*100)/39)*1.0

fletter =((fletter*100)/39)*1.0

print "There are", mletter, " males and", fletter, " females."
```

I have tried so many ways, I can't even remember them now!  My issues are that it's not editing the txt file properly, I have extra letters at the end of the string somehow.  And it refuses to round my math at the end so I'm ending up with 58 and 41 when it should be 59. And yes I did try the round function, didn't help.

Comment: Try `my_string.upper()` instead of `my_string.replace('m','M').replace('f','F')`.

Comment: Ok, I had it that way originally but I changed it thinking that something was wrong with it when the output wasn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues here:

1. You're doing integer division, then converting to floats. To fix this try: `mletter =((mletter*100)/39.0)` instead.
2. By using `r+` mode to overwrite the file you're not erasing old content first. That means when you first run the application it will remove the spaces and overwrite only the beginning with the new contents and leave the last few letters unchanged. Try mode `w` instead.
3. No need for setting stuff to 0 like this: `fletter = 0` You just overwrite it in the next line anyway.
4. You're not using `math` module, no need to import it.

(the result is 58.97435897435898 by the way, not 59)

Comment: Ok I wasn't sure what the w would do, b/c when I waas checking my text file it was empty in the end when it should have been written, but that makes sense.  And I was using the math module when I tried to use the round function, just forgot to take it back out.  Thank you

Comment: Also, I need it to be 59, which is part of the issue, both numbers should be a percent of a whole (and 58 and 41 are only 99) but for some reason with a decimal like .0 so I need it to round up to 59.0

Comment: Once you get the proper result, you can use round. Still not need for the `math` module - `round()` is global. Just print out `int(round(mletter))` (after other mentioned fixes)

Comment: Thank you, I did use round in the end to fix it, and got everything working somehow!

Answer (score 0):

I have made some improvements to your code below. The inline comments explain what each part does and what improvements it makes over your initial attempt.

```
main = raw_input("Enter the name of your file: ")

# make this a function since we use the equation more than once
def get_percent(part, whole):
    return 100 * float(part)/float(whole)

# make sure we handle the file not existing
try:
    with open(main, 'r+') as fd:
        # replace
        newstr = fd.read().replace(' ', '').upper()
        # after reading the file the file pointer will be at the end, we need to seek
        # back to the start of the file
        fd.seek(0)
        # remove the existing file contents
        fd.truncate()
        fd.write(newstr)
except IOError:
    # provide a friendly error and exit instead of a stacktrace
    raise SystemExit("Failed to open file %s" % main)


mletter = newstr.count('M')
fletter = newstr.count('F')
total = len(newstr)

# Using string formatting is often easier to read than string concatentation
print "There are %s%% males and %s%% females" %(
                                                get_percent(mletter, total),
                                                get_percent(fletter, total)
                                               )
```

Comment: I appreciate the comments in the code!  Thank you, I'm going to go see what I can do with my code.